# Как установить тему для кастомного layout toast?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-themes, android-toast

Мне нужно установить `AppTheme_Transparent` для моего кастомного `layout` `toast`. Но с приведенным ниже кодом этого не происходит. Может быть, я делаю это с неправильным контекстом ?!

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.toast_layout);

Context context = getApplicationContext();
context.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Transparent);
View layout = inflater.cloneInContext(context).inflate(R.layout.info_layout,
        linearLayout);

Toast toast = new Toast(context);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout));

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

---

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Это решает проблему, но не через тему. В принципе и так сойдет, спасибо.

Comment: @AndrewEfremov, зато оперативно :)